# Using Typed.JS with Express

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, typed.js

I'm trying to get Typed.JS with the express framework and ejs but having difficulty getting it to work.

I've installed and required typed.js and jquery in my app.js file but getting an error when importing from the library for some reason.

I've also tried to just link typed.js through CDN and putting the javascript in a script tag in the ejs template but no luck

```
//set all the dependencies in app.js
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require ("body-parser"),
    mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    methodOverride = require("method-override"),
    jquery = require("jquery"),
    Typed = require("typed.js");

//Routes in app.js
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("index", {Typed: Typed});
});


// In the index.ejs file

<script>
    var typed = new Typed('#typed', {
        stringsElement: '#typed-strings'
    });
</script>

<div id="typed-strings">
    <p>Typed.js is a <strong>JavaScript</strong> library.</p>
    <p>It <em>types</em> out sentences.</p>
</div>
<span id="typed"></span>
```

Comment: What errors are you running into?

Comment: You're trying to use a client side library on the server. This will not work.